# Why does the jQuery source code define functions 'twice' like "var someFunction = function someFunction()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, syntax

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I was doing some open-source learning reading the jQuery source code. I noticed some, not all, functions are defined 'circular', for instance

```
var isWindow = function isWindow( obj ) {
        return obj != null && obj === obj.window;
    };
```

My thoughts:

1. I know what the code does. It checks if an object is a window object, since it has the special property that it's field .window points to itself: window === window.window === window.window.window...
2. Does it have anything to do with *hoisting*, perhaps? if so, why would it be good to have isWindow function undefined at start? And once it reaches declaration, why not use anonymous function?

Thank you

Comment: *And once it reaches declaration, why not use anonymous function?* IIRC, always using named functions *used* to help with debugging, but that's not the case anymore with recent Javascript engines

Comment: They are not defined twice, nor does it relate to hoisting. `var isWindow` defines a *variable* called "isWindow". `= function isWindow()` then assigns a named function expression to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Perhaps the purpose is to *avoid* hosting (or maybe it's just a linting rule they use)

Comment: @emrhzc Naming a function helps with debugging, since the stacktrace will use the names instead of lots of (anonymous).

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, I can't say for sure why they chose variables vs function definitions. It's certainly possible it's to avoid hoisting but it's also just a linting rule, too (as in, not specifically chosen to avoid hoisting). One other option is to aid in minification, since `function someName` doesn't minify `someName` but `var someName` would, so if you use it multiple times, you get less of a footprint. I know the jQuery team is really rigorous in keeping the size small.

Comment: @VLAZ No, not really. I know the difference between function expression and function declaration, I just can't wrap my head around why someone would define it like that (both methods at the same time). Like, why not just use one methodology.

Comment: @Mc-Ac they *are* using one. One of several possible.

Comment: Two reasons: 1. The function name will be shown in the call stack instead of _anonymous_. 2. To call the function recursively by name.

Comment: I am unaware of any advantage in using var, if it will not be changed, so I assume it's an artifact of how [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/3.4.1/src) is organized (core modules are included directly, var modules are included as var when required).  If you're just learning JS, I recommend sticking with simple function (no var), and get into the habit of using `let` instead of `var`.  The later is scoped and will prevent stupid mistakes such as redeclaration.